# Uncaught TypeError: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor

Tags: three.js, hapi.js

I am new to THREE js I can't figure out the error

when I am run my code the following error is showing

> Uncaught TypeError: THREE.GLTFLoader is not a constructor

```
var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();

        loader.load('modelReq/Gully_update_2.gltf', 
            function (gltf) {

                scene.add(gltf.scene);
                gltf.animations; 
                gltf.scene;
                gltf.scenes; 
                gltf.cameras; 
                gltf.asset;


            },

            function (xhr) {
                console.log((xhr.loaded / xhr.total * 100 ) + '% loaded' );
            },

            function (error) {
                console.log( 'An error happened = ', error );
            }
        );
```

and error is at `var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();`

My html file :

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="js/plugins/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/TrackballControls.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/stats.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/plugins/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="animate">
        <canvas></canvas>
    </div>
```

and the GLTFLoader.js is in the path : `<script src="js/plugins/GLTFLoader.js"></script>`

Comment: Where are you getting your THREE.js from?
I would try loading it from the CDN off the web until you get it working. I think you are loading the version intended to be used with modules or something.

    <script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

Try getting your scripts from one of those locations ^.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

GLTFLoader is in a separate file...

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
```

edit: In the latest threejs the non-module versions have been removed.

instead now you have to import via:

import {GLTFLoader} from "https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"
in your .js.

Comment: Note: As part of the transition to ES6 Modules, the files in 'examples/js' were deprecated in May 2020 (r117) and will be deleted in December 2020 (r124).

Comment: This one is not working anymore.

Comment: They've removed the non module versions in latest threejs .. now things must be Imported from the jsm subdirectory instead. 

in your js:

import GLTFLoader  from "https://threejs.org/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"

Answer (score 6):

For me error was not including 'import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

Answer (score 0):

To resolve it, i had to do two things.

1-
'import { GLTFLoader } from 'three/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js'

2-
And remove THREE from THREE.GLTFLoader();

Just GLTFLoader();

Answer (score 0):

1. The Current version (`0.160.0`) of **ThreeJS** separated all loaders from `THREE` object. You can find **GLTF/OBJ/GLB/FBX/STL** loaders js files at https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/dev/examples/jsm/loaders and import it via **ThreeJS CDN** https://www.jsdelivr.com/package/npm/three?tab=files&path=examples%2Fjsm%2Floaders (list of all 3D formats loaders)

HTML Code will be like:

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.160.0/examples/jsm/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>`

2. Maybe if Loader object is wrapped to a module like **RequireJS/AMD** (also named as `GLTFLoader`) you call a wrapped module object that contains loader inside. So you need to call it:

`var loader = new GLTFLoader.GLTFLoader();`